# How to add TLD to search exception in Safari

Tags: macos, safari, tld

How can I add `.locahost` to the list of TLDs that Safari will **load** — instead of searching — without supplying a protocol? Alternatively (or perhaps additionally), how do I get Safari to stop removing the `http://` protocol from the URL?

---

I've been using `project.localhost` to handle local development for a while, now that `.dev` is no longer a viable development TLD. But I'm getting frustrated with Safari's default behavior. What I'd like to do is prevent Safari from submitting the domain name to the search engine.

Desired:

1. enter `project.localhost` into address bar
2. browser loads `http://project.localhost`

I would be satisfied with Safari not removing the `http://` in the address bar, but I can't find a way to do that, either.

What actually happens:

1. enter `project.localhost` into address bar
2. browser sends `project.localhost` to Duck Duck Go
3. user is tempted to test the ballistic properties of keyboard

Or, after I've loaded `http://project.localhost` and then try to add something after the current URL:

1. click in address bar, URL has been shortened to `project.localhost`
2. add `/test.html` to end
3. browser sends `project.localhost/test.html` to Duck Duck Go
4. user considers software violence

Comment: This is clearly an extremely annoying Safari weirdness.

Comment: Indeed. If I could figure out installing Chromium – not Chrome – I might use it, instead. I've even tried installing Opera. When the installer fails, it doesn't build confidence.

Comment: I'm currently pursuing development of a Safari extension that listens for the `beforeSearch` event. I can get it to abort the search when the query matching a pattern, but haven't yet figured out how to supply a replacement URL to Safari.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that the Safari extension might be a long term solution. At this moment, I can't manage the developer membership cost. But here's the working code, for Future Me and anyone else looking into this.

In the extension's global page `<script>`:

```
(function() {
    safari.application.addEventListener("beforeSearch", function(event) {
        if (event.query.split("/")[0].split(".").pop() == "localhost") {
            event.preventDefault();
            safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab.url = "http://" + event.query;
        }
    }, true);
})();
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this!  I know it's been a while, but I'm just encountering this problem.  I'll be happy to publish a free tool for this if you can help me turn this into a real app.  (I have not worked with Safari extensions before).

Comment: @DannySung This is actually the only time I've tried my hand at a Safari extension. This many years later, and it's still essentially unsolved. It was easier to learn self-signed certificates and serve locally over HTTPS. Ironic.

Answer (score 3):

If you just type the trailing '/', then the search will be bypassed.

Answer (score 2):

I just found this question while looking for a solution to the same problem.  Good news, there's an easy solution that I just stumbled upon after not finding an answer.

Open System Preferences
Open Network
Click Advanced button
Click Proxies tab

Then in the "Bypass proxy settings for these Hosts & Domains:" add in localhost to the list.  Here's what I did with mine.  I'm using .home for my local domains in my PiHole. Now if I type "router.home" into Safari my router's config page loads up.

[image: screen shot of configured preferences]

Comment: And that works without even needing a check in the box?! I see, not even related to the "Select a protocol to configure" list. Must explore.

Comment: Maybe I need to restart, or something. So far, this isn't working for me. I'm still excited that perhaps there's a fix and I'm just not doing it right.

Comment: @MarkPriddy sorry, I hadn't seen your comment. I'm also running a PiHole and added a local DNS record for each of the boxes.  So there might be something additional at play in my setup.  They weren't working for me on first try which is when I found this post.  After adding "*.home" like above "router.home" started working for me along with the others.